# Help with further TeXing

Tags: math-mode, diagrams, arrows

I wanted to recreate a diagram in LaTeX, so I did my best and created something with matrices. I am really content, but I still don't have the arrows with 'reële nulpunten' and 'complexe nulpunten' and the two arrows below. Could someone try to recreate these? I really have no idea how to do this...

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.1in,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\cfbox}[2]{%
\colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
{\color{#1}%
\fbox{\color{currentcolor}#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{blauw}{HTML}{0074C8}
\definecolor{bruin}{HTML}{753700}
\definecolor{groen}{HTML}{00E12C}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.2}
\begin{tabular}{ l c c }
& & Galoisgroep \\
Splijtlichaam & \cfbox{bruin}{{\color{bruin}$\Sigma$}\hspace{5pt} $(x \tikzmark{a}- a_1)(x \tikzmark{b}- a_2)(x \tikzmark{c}- a_3)(x \tikzmark{d}- a_4)(x \tikzmark{e}-\tikzmark{f} a_5)$} & $\{e\}$ \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Intermediaire lichamen} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cfbox{blauw}{ \color{blauw}{$\Sigma \cap \mathbb{R}$} \hspace{5pt} {\color{black} $(x - a_1)(x - a_2)(x - a_3)(x^2 + Ax + B)$}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_2$} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cfbox{groen}{\color{groen}$\mathbb{Q}[a_1]$ \hspace{3cm}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\operatorname{Gal}({\color{groen}\mathbb{Q}[a_1]}/ {\color{bruin}\Sigma})$} \\
Grondlichaam & \cfbox{purple}{{\color{purple} $\mathbb{Q}$} \hspace{5pt} $x^5 -6x + 3$} & $\operatorname{Gal}({\color{purple}\mathbb{Q}}/ {\color{bruin}\Sigma})$

\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \coordinate (x) at ($({pic cs:f})-({pic cs:e})$);
  \foreach \i in {a,b,c,d,e} \coordinate (\i) at ($({pic cs:\i})+.5*(x)+(0,9pt)$);
  \draw (a) -- ++(0,5pt) coordinate (p) -| (c) (b) -- (b |- p) node [anchor=south] {\footnotesize{Reële nulpunten}};
  \draw (d) -- (p -| d) -- (e |- p) node [midway,anchor=south] {\footnotesize{Complexe nulpunten}} -- (e) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to align things using a tabular or array?

Comment: @cfr I edited my post using tabular

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

Using your revised code, which incorporates my original answer below, to answer your follow-up question, you can add additional `\tikzmark{}`s wherever you wish and then annotate the equations in the `tikzpicture` overlay as desired.

For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\usepackage{multirow,array,tabularx}

\newcommand{\cfbox}[2]{%
\colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
{\color{#1}%
\fbox{\color{currentcolor}#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{blauw}{HTML}{0074C8}
\definecolor{bruin}{HTML}{753700}
\definecolor{groen}{HTML}{00E12C}

\makebox[\linewidth-50pt]{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.2}
    \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
      & & Galoisgroep \\
      Splijtlichaam & \cfbox{bruin}{{\color{bruin}$\Sigma$}\hspace{5pt} $(x \tikzmark{a}- a_1)(x \tikzmark{b}- a_2)(x \tikzmark{c}- a_3)(x \tikzmark{d}- a_4)(x \tikzmark{e}-\tikzmark{f} a_5)$} & $\{e\}$ \\
      \multirow{2}{*}[-1ex]{Intermediaire lichamen} & \cfbox{blauw}{ \color{blauw}{$\Sigma \cap \mathbb{R}$} \hspace{5pt} {\color{black} $(x - a_1)(x - a_2)(x - a_3)(x^2 + Ax + B)$}} & $C_2$ \\
      & \cfbox{groen}{\color{groen}$\mathbb{Q}[a\tikzmark{h}_1]$\hspace{20mm}}\tikzmark{i} & $\operatorname{Gal}({\color{groen}\mathbb{Q}[a_1]}/ {\color{bruin}\Sigma})$ \\
      Grondlichaam & \cfbox{purple}{{\color{purple} $\mathbb{Q}$} \hspace{5pt} $x^5 \tikzmark{g}- 6x + 3$}\tikzmark{j} & $\operatorname{Gal}({\color{purple}\mathbb{Q}}/ {\color{bruin}\Sigma})$\\
    \end{tabular}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, font=\footnotesize]
  \coordinate (x) at ($({pic cs:f})-({pic cs:e})$);
  \foreach \i in {a,b,c,d,e,g} \coordinate (\i) at ($({pic cs:\i})+.5*(x)+(0,9pt)$);
  \foreach \i in {h,i,j} \coordinate (\i) at (pic cs:\i);
  \draw (a) -- ++(0,5pt) coordinate (p) -| (c) (b) -- (b |- p) node [anchor=south] {Reële nulpunten};
  \draw (d) -- (p -| d) -- (e |- p) node [midway,anchor=south] {Complexe nulpunten} -- (e) ;
  \draw [->] (h |- i) [out=-90,in=90] to node [pos=.6, left, xshift=-5pt] {some label here} (g);
  \draw [->] (j) +(2.5pt,.5\baselineskip) [bend right] to node [midway, right] {5}([yshift=.5\baselineskip,xshift=2.5pt]i) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: annotated equations]

---

**Original**

There are doubtless better ways to manage the alignment of the equations but here's just a way to draw the annotations at the top using **tikzmark**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\newcommand{\cfbox}[2]{%
\colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
{\color{#1}%
\fbox{\color{currentcolor}#2}}%
}

\definecolor{blauw}{HTML}{0074C8}
\definecolor{bruin}{HTML}{753700}
\definecolor{groen}{HTML}{00E12C}


\begin{document}

\hspace{-50pt}
$ \begin{matrix}
& & \ \ \ $Galoisgroep$ \\
& & \\
$\ \ \ \ \ Splijtlichaam$ \hspace{43.5pt}& \cfbox{bruin}{${\Large{\color{bruin}\Sigma}}\hspace{5pt} (x \tikzmark{a}- a_1)(x \tikzmark{b}- a_2)(x \tikzmark{c}- a_3)(x \tikzmark{d}- a_4)(x \tikzmark{e}-\tikzmark{f} a_5)$} & \ \ \ \ \{e\} \\
& & \\

\end{matrix}$

\hspace{-50pt}Intermediare lichamen \ \ \ $\left[ \begin{matrix}\ \ \ \cfbox{blauw}{${\color{blauw} \Sigma \cap \mathbb{R}} \hspace{5pt} (x - a_1)(x - a_2)(x - a_3)(x^2 + Ax + B)$ } & C_2 \\ & \\ \cfbox{groen}{${\color{groen}\mathbb{Q}[a_1] \hspace{1cm} \hspace{1cm} }$} & \operatorname{Gal}({\color{groen}\mathbb{Q}[a_1]}/ {\color{bruin}\Sigma}) \end{matrix}\right.$

\hspace{-50pt}$ \begin{matrix}
& & \\
$ \ \ \ Grondlichaam$ & \hspace{3,7cm} \cfbox{purple}{${\color{purple} \mathbb{Q}} \hspace{5pt} x^5 -6x + 3$} & \hspace{2,9cm} \operatorname{Gal}({\color{purple}\mathbb{Q}}/ {\color{bruin}\Sigma})
\end{matrix} $
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \coordinate (x) at ($({pic cs:f})-({pic cs:e})$);
  \foreach \i in {a,b,c,d,e} \coordinate (\i) at ($({pic cs:\i})+.5*(x)+(0,7.5pt)$);
  \draw (a) -- ++(0,5pt) coordinate (p) -| (c) (b) -- (b |- p) node [anchor=south] {Label here};
  \draw (d) -- (p -| d) -- (e |- p) node [midway,anchor=south] {Label here} -- (e) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: annotated top]

Comment: Thanks, this works just fine! Do you also have a solution to the problem with the arrows below? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can use the same technique: adding `tikzmark`s and then creating arrows within the `tikzpicture`. ***But this really doesn't seem to me a good way to layout the equations.*** Certainly it creates bad boxes. Those can be avoided, but the manual spacing is pretty nasty.

Comment: @CauchytheDog I see you've found an easier alignment method ;). See edit above for updated code responding to your new question.